# print out array become garbage

Tags: c++, algorithm, syntax, type-conversion

I have a function that sort out a number of elements(double) in an array(aArray) and elements(int) in an array(bArray) in a function. However when i print out it turn out to be garbage.

aSize refer to the size of aArray;
aArray[aSize];

bSize refer to the size of bArray;
bArray[bSize];

e.g 
for a array:

```c++
aArray[5] = { 2.5, 4.5, 3.5, 7.5, 5.5 }
```

after algorithm:

```c++
aArray[5] = { 2.5, 3.5, 4.5, 5.5, 7.5}
```

for b array:

```c++
bArray[3] = { 3, 1, 5 }
```

after algorithm:

```c++
bArray[3] = { 1, 3, 5}
```

after this code below it should print out the location of aArray[]

e.g:

```c++
cArray[3] = { 2.5, 3.5, 5.5 }
```

here the print out code:

```c++
int main(){

            int bSize,tem;
            double tem1;
            cout<<endl<<endl<<"recalculation: [ ";
            for(int t=0;t<bSize;t++){
                tem=bArray[t];
                tem1=aArray[tem];
                tem1=cArray[t];

              cout<<cArray[t]<<" ";
            }
}
```

output:

> recalculation: [ 6.95324e-310 6.95322e-310 1.62597e-260 ]

Help pls. thanks

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do in that for loop

Comment: Initialization means you assign a value to the variable. double temp; is a variable declaration with no initialization.

Comment: Please post the actual code, not an approximation of it.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays in C++ are zero based, accessing the item #5 (because the indez of the elements in the array goes 0 to 4) will result in garbage.
You should also initialize your variables (bSize)

Answer (score 0):

I got it, actually when i print out the array tem1 = cArray[t] whereby cArray[t] isn't declared so the key to this question is actually

> cArray[t] = tem;

lol!!